# Assigning a string contained in an NSArray to an object contained in a different NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, loops, nsarray

I have these two arrays:

```
NSArray *nameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cow", @"Haystack", @"Cow Bell", @"Branding Iron", @"Herding Dog",
                              @"Camel", @"Tractor", @"Warehouse", @"Milking Pipeline", @"Robotic Milker", @"Amusement Park",
                              @"Nitrous Kit", @"Mooship", nil];
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5, cell6, cell7, cell8, cell9, cell10, cell11, cell12, cell13, nil];
```

The cells are all `CCLabelTTF` objects, so they all have a string property. I want to assign the labels in `itemArray` with their corresponding string in `nameArray`. I've looked up the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html) and what I think I need to use is `- (void)makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector` but I'm not entirely sure what I need to use as a selector.

I am using a for loop to try to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= itemArray.count; i++) {
    [itemArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector()];
    i++;
}
```

Am I right in using `makeObjectsPerformSelector:`? If not then what do I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use `makeObjectsPerformSelect:` in a loop. It does the loop for you.

But since you need to extract the right label from the name array, using `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` isn't really an option here.

You want:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < itemArray.count; i++) {
    CCLabelTTF *cell = itemArray[i];
    NSString *label = nameArray[i];
    cell.someProperty = label;
}
```

Also note the use of `<` instead of `<=` in the `for` statement.